# How can I reproduce a Drupal install without using an installation profile

Tags: installation

I need to be able to re-create a Drupal install (as a sub-domain) using the minimal install profile, but I then need to:

1. Install and configure a few additional modules
2. Configure a few content types

As it stands, I have installed and enabled Views, Field UI, and a custom module in the sub-domain. How do I export the settings into something I can re-produce without having the user have to go through the process of the Drupal install?

What I plan on doing:

1. Create a fresh install with all modules enabled and configured as desired (Views, etc)
2. Export the SQL

But this doesn't address more bespoke problems...any suggestions?

Where do I even start?

It's important to note that I do not think I am looking for a profile install as the user will never know any of the details of the server (these are all generated automatically when user signs up).

Comment: Why would you not use a profile? I think that is the way to go.

Comment: Its a hosted webapp...I don't (can't) want to bother users with MySQL details...All I want to know from them is their account details (username, password, sub-domain) and I will create everything else on the fly.

Maybe I have to re-investigate the profile approach and just hide/remove those details from the process...

Comment: Have you looked at aegir?

Comment: In your title you are mentioning [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) - how did this module failed to satisfy your needs?

Comment: I see your question edited - now, is there any reason not to use installation profiles? They are tools literally created to solve your use case. Install profiles can be used by Drush as well as via UI, you know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to install Drupal without an installation profile but I don't think that's really what you're trying to achieve, maybe edit the question? A couple of ways to achieve what you're wanting:

1. You'd be best off using `drush site-install`:

   This way you can pass database credentials, site name and site username/password all in one command.
2. Either that or you can import a copy of an already installed Drupal site and change all the configuration to match the new domain and database details. I don't have any information about this method except that I think it would be much more difficult and time consuming than using site-install.

Comment: Drush could work

Answer (score 0):

- You can build the base install

  Use backup and migrate module or myPHPAdmin to backup the site

  Use Putty-SSH tar command to backup the fileset
      Create new database for new install

  Use Putty-SSH tar command to restore/mirror the fileset

  Rewrite/edit settings.php with database user/pw, conf[] variable
  options and perms

  Use phpMySQL and restore the backup and migrate file created in step
  1

Simplified but works. BASH Scripts to do this are the automated technique.